# What inspries the child and adult characters from Shin Chan to have squished heads and rigid jaws?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, crayon-shin-chan

Before I begin, it's important to note that the way heads are drawn varies from art style depending on the mass of the width and length of a head of a skinny character or the mass of the width and length of a head of a fat character, it varies in the artist's style since there's no perfect way to draw heads and also no one way to draw heads, but I'll say that what inspires that child characters of Shin Chan to have b-shaped heads and the adult characters with the females having rigid jaws?